# Is the CSS broken? Sidebar overlaps footer in "Ask Question" page

Tags: bug, css

When asking a new question, if I scroll down I can see this beauty:

[image]

Which seem to be a bug... I'm using firefox on W7.

Comment: Also reported on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136849/259867); SE explicitly declined to change this behavior of the sidebar.